# SwiftUI List only taps content

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have a List in SwiftUI that I populate with a custom SwiftUI cell, the issue is that on tap I need to do some stuff and the tap only works when you click the text in the cell, if you click any empty space it will not work. How can I fix this?

```
struct SelectDraftView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SelectDraftViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.drafts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        DraftPostCell(draft: viewModel.drafts[index])
                            .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        guard let delete = indexSet.map({ viewModel.drafts[$0] }).first else { return }
                        viewModel.delete(draft: delete)
                    }
                
            }
                .background(Color.white)
            Spacer()

        }
    }
}

struct DraftPostCell: View {
    var draft: CDDraftPost
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(draft.title ?? "")
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                .font(Font(UIFont.uStadium.helvetica(ofSize: 14)))
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            if let body = draft.body {
                Text(body)
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 40)
                    .font(Font(UIFont.uStadium.helvetica(ofSize: 14)))
            }
            Text(draft.date?.toString(format: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy") ?? "")
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                .font(Font(UIFont.uStadium.helvetica(ofSize: 12)))
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably late but this will be useful for anyone checking this in the future.
You need to add `.background()` modifier to your view before you do `.onTapGesture{...}`

so in your `ForEach` code would be modified like this:

```
ForEach(viewModel.drafts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    DraftPostCell(draft: viewModel.drafts[index])
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // you should use the frame parameter according to your needs, but if you want your cell to occupy the whole width of your scroll view, use this one
        .background()  // this makes the empty portions of view 'non-transparent', so those portions also receive the tap gesture
        .onTapGesture {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
}
```

P.S if you need the whole portion of your scroll view cell to receive the tap gesture you'll also need to add `.frame(...)` modifier, so it has the exact background you want

Answer (score 0):

try adding `.frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity)` just after `DraftPostCell(...)`. You can also use a `minWidth:` if required.

EDIT-1: the code I use for testing (on real devices ios 15.6, macCatalyst, not Previews):

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SelectDraftView()
    }
}

class SelectDraftViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var drafts: [
        CDDraftPost] = [
            CDDraftPost(title: "item 1", date: Date(), body: "body 1"),
            CDDraftPost(title: "item 2", date: Date(), body: "body 4"),
            CDDraftPost(title: "item 3", date: Date(), body: "body 3")]
    
    func delete(draft: CDDraftPost) {  }
}

struct CDDraftPost: Codable {
    var title: String?
    var date: Date?
    var body: String?
}

struct SelectDraftView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = SelectDraftViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.drafts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    DraftPostCell(draft: viewModel.drafts[index])
                        .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .border(.red)  // <-- for testing
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("----> onTapGesture")
                            //  presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    guard let delete = indexSet.map({ viewModel.drafts[$0] }).first else { return }
                    viewModel.delete(draft: delete)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.white)
            Spacer()
            
        }
    }
}

struct DraftPostCell: View {
    var draft: CDDraftPost
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(draft.title ?? "")
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
            //    .font(Font(UIFont.uStadium.helvetica(ofSize: 14)))
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            if let body = draft.body {
                Text(body)
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 40)
                //   .font(Font(UIFont.uStadium.helvetica(ofSize: 14)))
            }
            Text(draft.date?.formatted() ?? "")
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
            //  .font(Font(UIFont.uStadium.helvetica(ofSize: 12)))
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, it also pushed all the content to the center which is not ideal

Comment: strange, it works well for me. Do you have `SelectDraftView` embedded in some other code that you are not showing us? In my tests, I just put it in a `ContentView` on its own.

Comment: Nope it's just inside the ForEach with content shape and on Tap

Comment: I'll update my answer, with the code I used for my tests. Note, to avoid centering, just add `, alignment: .leading` to the frame.

Comment: are you saying you have `SelectDraftView` in another ForEach loop?